# How to return HTML to the Tooltip in rCharts

Tags: r, tooltip, nvd3.js, rcharts

Is there a way to return a hyperling in the tooltip? (p2 is the plotted data)

```
p2$chart(tooltipContent = "#! function(key, x, y, e, graph ){return 'link'.link('http://www.google.com')} !#")
```

There is what seems to be a hyperlink displayed in the tooltip, but clicking on it does not elicit a response. I'm fairly new with R and rCharts, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would tag this question with nvd3 too, since rCharts merely hands off the tooltipContent function to javascript verbatim, just stripping off the #! tags. Did you try plain old html?

Comment: @Ramnath: I tried
p2$chart(tooltipContent = "#! function(key, x, y, e, graph ){ <a href='http://www.google.com'>link</a>} !#")
but I end up losing my entire plot

Comment: This works for me `p2$chart(tooltipContent = "#! function(key, x, y, e, graph ){return '<a href=google.com>link</a>';} !#")`. But due to the hover, it is unclickable. See the discussion [here](http://www.rqgg.net/topic/uyqw-clickable-datapoints-that-launches-closeable-modal-window-in-d3-chart-nvd3.html)

Comment: If this addresses your question, can you answer it yourself and accept it, so that it can be closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:
    p2$chart(tooltipContent = "#! function(key, x, y, e, graph ){return 'link';} !#")

but the link is unclickable due to the hover

(Special thanks to @Ramnath for help with this issue)